# How to store my data into one object in my Activity class and send that object to another Activity class

Tags: android

I have to store my data (mobileNumber, name, message) into an object in my Activity class, then i want to send that object to another Activity class.  How can i do that?? And i want to know the procedure to retrieve the object in other Activity class. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read this post: 
[How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

I think you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

check this ans.. [Pass custom class object from one intent to ither intent without parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024875/1140237)

parcelable also the option to pass custom class object from one to other intent